# Receive data in Win Form application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

We have a requirement where our Win Form application needs to receive some data from Telephone application. Win Form application is used by agents, and we have their smart desktop application built using 3rd Party tool that receive Phone Calls. Now Whenever that Smart Desktop receives a phone call, it should pass information to Our C# winform application.

Now because of inter-op I have decided to make it a WCF Service, basic HTTP Binding. First question, is it the right choice?

Second Problem, I feel is I have to run my win form application as Admin to make it host a WCF Service. I see this as a Problem, I can't ask every agent (1500+) to open app as Administrator. Is their solution for it?

I can ask my Network admin, to allow open specific port on every machine using "NETSH" command. But I am worried he might come with an argument of some security issue. As our machines are in our Domain I don't see this as Security Issue. Am I right?

Looking for advise. Thanks IN Advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly both applications are hosted on same machine and they will only talk to each other, there will be no network calls from different machines? And can you explain a bit more what is inter-op you are referring to?

Comment: Have you considered to use a Message queue such as MSMQ for that? I think it's going to be easier to use a message queue then to rewrite your application as a WCF host.

Comment: @Enes thanks for the response. Yes both apps will be hosted on same server, though the calling App is not a c# app. Its a telephony app, that renders a web page on every agent's machine. Those guys will rendering some javascript code on that page that will do the call. So I have to do it HTTP, that's requirement. I did manage to make it work using "netsh http add url... ". But now I am worried if it will cause a security issue.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think above comment will answer your question. MSMQ using Javascript might not be that convenient. I will though read about MSMQ, how easy it is to place a command in MSMQ through javascript sender.

Comment: You could consider using a `NamedPipe`. It seems unusual to listen on a port for inter-process communication on the same server.